# JSX element type 'xxx' is not a constructor function for JSX elements. Property 'yyy' is protected in type 'xxx' but public in type 'ElementClass'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to import an React class called [`Vega-Lite`](https://github.com/vega/voyager/blob/master/src/components/vega-lite/index.tsx#L18) from a project called [`Voyager`](https://github.com/vega/voyager).

Here's my code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {VegaLite} from 'datavoyager/build/components/vega-lite';

export interface Props {
  spec: any;
  logger: any;
}

export const View = ({spec, logger}: Props) => {
  return(
    <VegaLite spec={spec} logger={logger}/>
  );
};
```

Here's my error:

> [ts] JSX element type 'VegaLite' is not a constructor function for JSX
>   elements.   Property 'componentDidMount' is protected in type
>   'VegaLite' but public in type 'ElementClass'.

I know that in the class [`Vega-Lite`](https://github.com/vega/voyager/blob/master/src/components/vega-lite/index.tsx#L18), the function `componentDidMount()` is indeed `protected`. But how do I fix this error?

PS: I've tried setting `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` to `true` in my `tsconfig.json`, but the same error persists.

Comment: Do you have a line `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true` in `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: @Andrew yes I've tried that, but that doesn't remove the error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to downgrade your react typings to below `15.0.25` version. Starting from `15.0.25`version all of the lifecycle methods are forced to be public.

Here is an issue about it: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/16893

A better solution would be creating an issue in `voyager` repo which would tell them that their components are incompatible with newer react typings. They use `^15.0.8`.

Comment: I had to upgrade to @types/react@16.0.4 to fix a 'xxxx is not a constructor for JSX.Elements' ts warning